# Laravel 5.7 Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User]

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, factory, laravel-5.7

What's going on with Laravel 5.7 Factories? When I run the factory on `php artisan tinker` it works fine. But when I use it with Unit Tests it throws an error:

> *`Unable to locate factory with name [default] [App\User]`*

Here's my Unit Test

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use \App\User;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->user = factory(User::class, 1)->create()->first();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function a_sample_test()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(!empty($this->user));

    }
}
```

And `UserFactory` was generated by running
*`php artisan make:factory UserFactory --model=User`*

This is my factory for User on /database/factories

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(\App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

I've run to similar questions here on SO, but they all seem to have the same answer to use `\App\Model::class` instead of `App\Model::class`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ohh shoot! **`parent::setUp()`** fixed this issue.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    // more codes here
}
```

Comment: not fixed me i'm still get same errors. how can i fixed it ?

Answer (score 15):

The error is also thrown due to ***importing*** the wrong ***TestCase*** and not just `parent::setUp();` only

-

`use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;` [*WRONG*: and throws this error]

---

`use Tests\TestCase;` [CORRECT]

Comment: With Laravel 7 doing unit testing, this is the only thing that worked for me. But this is the default class import if you create unit test using command line.